# Program that uses Mac status bar

Tags: macos, rubymotion, macruby, pyobjc

I'm looking to make a program that would have an icon and drop-down menu on the status bar. Are there any resources on how to do this? I'd prefer building it in Ruby, but I also wouldn't mind doing it in Python, C++ or Bash (if possible).

Comment: It's called *status bar*, see [Status Bar Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/StatusBar/StatusBar.html) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [MacRuby](http://macruby.org/), [RubyMotion](http://www.rubymotion.com/), or [PyObjC](http://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/).

For programming in Ruby, MacRuby is the open source version and precursor to RubyMotion (which recently added support for Mac development).

For programming in Python, take a look at PyObjC. PyObjC is a wrapper while MacRuby and RubyMotion are built directly on top of the objective-c runtime, so they will be more performant than PyObjC.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at MacRuby => http://macruby.org? Maybe something like this would do what you want: https://gist.github.com/245402/f4a7bc1c7b32bd3975d0203f22cd7a920af2fe56

Answer (score 1):

This may have appeared only in the time since the previous answers:  As a Python option, have a look at Jared Suttles's [rumps](https://github.com/jaredks/rumps); the name signifies "Ridiculously Uncomplicated Mac os x Python Statusbar."